# is there a way to do multiple file operations in ffmpeg input

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I have gopro video's that need heavy color editing and i have figured out to disassemble my videos in high quality frames -> converting them with ART-rawconverter -> Reassembeling them into lossless ffv1 video format.

commands are these :

```
ffmpeg -i VID.MP4  VID/out%04d.tiff

ART-cli -p VID/out0001.tiff.arp -o VID/tmp/ -c VID/*.tiff

ffmpeg -i out%04d.png -c:v ffv1 -qscale:v 0 OUTFFV1.avi
```

Now, it works... but it saves a sh!tload of tiffs on my harddrive and its just a faf.

Is there a way to get like --
`ffmpeg -i (ART-cli -i (ffmpeg -i VID.MP4))`
so everything happens in ram instead of saving it all on the disk?